# How to use Flexjson JSONDeserializer?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, flexjson

I have a string:

```
 [{"product_id":"2","name":'stack"'},{"product_id":"2","name":"overflow"}]"
```

How can I use Flexjson's JSONDeserializer to obtain all `product_id`s from the above string?

I have a class called `productinformation` which has fields like `product_id` and `name`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `JSONDeserializer.use()` methods to tell it how to deserialize the array and each object in the array, in this case of class `ProductInformation` . The product_id attribute does not match up with the standard naming that flexjson expects, so your properties on the object will need to have an underscore in them.

```
String products= "[{\"product_id\": \"123\",\"name\":\"stack\"},{\"product_id\": \"456\",\"name\":\"overflow\"}]";
List<ProductInformation> productInfoList = new JSONDeserializer<List<ProductInformation> >()
    .use(null, ArrayList.class)
    .use("values",ProductInformation.class)
    .deserialize(products);

for(ProductInformation productInformation : productInfoList){
    System.out.println(productInformation.getProduct_id();
}
```

The section on "Deserialization Without the Training Wheels" in [Deserialization section of the docs](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/#Deserialization) goes into additional details on the other cases to consider if the type information is not included in the JSON string.

Comment: pardon my ignorance but what is meant by--- use ("values",ProductInformation.class)..what is "values"...

Comment: "values" is a specific name that flexjson uses to refer to the members of a collection, in this case the list. This is basically saying "each of the members of this list should be deserialized into a `ProductInformation` object.

Comment: Some minutes ago i have the requirement that to serilize again a list<productInformation> into above string..could u show me some ideas in this direction also...

Comment: @ rob : hey i posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122368/how-i-can-serilaize-a-list-of-object-using-flexjson ...  if u know the answer  please comment there...