# How I can create a complex string in Java efficiently?

Tags: java

I want to create a string which will look like the following:

```
 "[{"product_id":"123","name":"stack"},{"product_id":"456","name":"overflow"}]"
```

I have the `product_id` and `name` in two arrays.  How can I create the above type of string most efficiently?

Comment: I saw your comment on your [related deserialization question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7099803/193874). Do you want to do the conversion from two arrays or from a `List<ProductInformation>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it turns out you already have a `List<ProductInformation>`, then the default serialization with flexjson with an exclude will give you the string:

```
String jsonResult = new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize(listOfProductInformation);
```

Regarding performance, your best bet is to use a good profiler to look at your overall application. This will identify your true hotspots/bottlenecks and if it turns out this serialization process is a hotspot, you can spend time tuning as @Ali mentions and running it back through the profiler or performance test harness to measure the impact.

Answer (score 14):

This looks like JSON. You should use a JSON library.

There are plenty out there (see [this page](http://www.json.org/), scroll almost to the end), but

- [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ([Sample Usage](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples)) or
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) ([Sample Usage](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Simple_Data_Binding_Example))

are the ones I'd use.

Comment: Nice answer with samples and everything.

Comment: +1 @Sean Patrick Floyd, good recommendations on using a library and which one to use - that will provide flexibility and code clarity if there is a future requirement to add new fields, have more complex hierarchical relationships, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look on the Java String Formatter:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have 2 arrays one containing and product_id and the other containing the values and both of these are in correct order.

I would create my own java object (POJO) that had two fields `product_id` and `name` then take your two arrays and create one array (or list) of POJOs each POJO containing the product_id and name. Then I would just use Jackson or Gson to create my JSON.

These libraries give you a JSON representation of a Java Objects, so in this case you will have to make sure that you have a list or even an array of objects which contain your `product_id` and `name`.

If you insist on doing it the hard-way (or no external library way), then I would create a template String and repeatedly call replace on it and add it to a StringBuffer. The StringBuffer is important if the string can be very large. Something like:

```
String template = "{\"product_id\":\"productId\",\"name\":\"productName\"}";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer("[");

for(int i=0; i<myProductArray.length; i++){
   String temp = template.replace("productId",myProductArray[i]);
   temp = temp.replace("productName",myNameArray[i]);
   if(result.length() > 1)
      result.append(",");
   result.append(temp);
}
result.append("]");
return result.toString();
```

If you can replace the `template` `String` with a `StringBuffer` and manipulate that directly, it'll make a ton of difference performance wise for large Strings.

Regards,