# How can I  serialize a list of objects using flex json?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a list of an object like follows

```
 List<ProductInfo>
```

I want to serialize it using flex json so that it should like

```
 [{"product_id":"2","name":'stack"'},{"product_id":"2","name":"overflow"}]"
```

for deserializing from the above string into a List of Objects I am using the following code

```
 final List<ProductInformation> productInformationList = new JSONDeserializer<List<ProductInformation>>().use(null, ArrayList.class)
            .use("values", ProductInformation.class).deserialize(parameterValue);
```

for serializing the object to string I am doing this but it's not working....I am missing something...

```
final String serializizedString = new JSONSerializer().serialize(productInformationList);
```

What do I need to serialize the object into a string?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post some code that demonstrates your best attempt at accomplishing your goal and ask a specific question about a section that is causing an error or is giving you trouble...

Comment: @maerics : do u have any idea about flexjson..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never played with [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) before but after downloading it and playing with it here is what I've come up with:

```java
public class TestFlexJson {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ProductInfo p1 = new ProductInfo(1, "Stack");
    ProductInfo p2 = new ProductInfo(2, "Overflow");
    List<ProductInfo> infos = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);
    String s = new JSONSerializer()
        .exclude("*.class", "description")
        //.include("productId", "name")
        // EDIT: the "include" call is irrelevant for this example.
        .serialize(infos);
    System.out.println(s);
    // => [{"name":"Stack","productId":1},{"name":"Overflow","productId":2}]
    List<ProductInfo> ls = new JSONDeserializer<List<ProductInfo>>().deserialize(s);
    System.out.println(ls);
    // => [{name=Stack, productId=1}, {name=Overflow, productId=2}]
  }
  public static class ProductInfo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String desc; // Not used, to demonstrate "exclude".
    public ProductInfo(int id, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }
    public int getProductId() { return this.id; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getDescription() { return this.desc; }
  }
}
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: try with some string in the product name like "this is the (rot) / milk , i just drank yesterday"

Comment: Yup, still works fine for me using JDK 1.6.0_26 and flexjson-2.1.

Comment: even if i use .include("productID", "productName") why he is giving back the string-> [{"name":"this is the (rot) / milk , i just drank yesterday","productId":"1"},{"name":"Overflow","productId":"2"}]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  The `include` method is apparently only relevant for object attributes which are collections, all non-collection attributes are included by default (see my edited answer).

Comment: Actually I was trying to ask why in the serilization method he was giving strings like "name" and "productId" then i found out now that it's the get method names of ProductInformation which decides the string name. Thanks a lot for ur help n support. I haven't tried this but try on monday morning. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
List<ProductInfo> ls = new JSONDeserializer<ArrayList<ProductInfo>>().use("values", ProductInfo.class).deserialize(s);
```

Follow this [link](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/changelog.html) or read care fully following

Refactored path listings for Maps and Collections. In prior versions there was no way to specify both the concrete top of a Collection/Map AND the concrete class contained within. The path language was not verbose enough. Now you can specify both the concrete collection AND the concrete class contained within. if person.friends is a path that points to java.util.Map. For example,

```
new JSONDeserializer<Person>()
    .use( "person.friends", HashMap.class )
    .use("person.friends.keys", Relation.class )
    .use( "person.friends.values", Person.class )
```

By adding "keys" and "values" to the path person.friends you can specify the actual concrete classes to use for the keys and values of the Map. For Collections you can simply append "values" to specify the containing class. For example:

```
new JSONDeserializer<List<Person>>().use( "people", ArrayList.class ).use("people.values", Person.class )
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the class property must be included if you need to deserialize your json into a collection. In the above example, the json string was deserialized as follows:

```
List<ProductInfo> ls = new JSONDeserializer<List<ProductInfo>>().deserialize(s);     
System.out.println(ls);     
// => [{name=Stack, productId=1}, {name=Overflow, productId=2}]
```

If you were to try to access an element directly, lets say `ls.get(0)`y you would receive a `ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to ProductInfo`.

You must serialize your object to include the class property in order to appropriately deserialize into a collection.