# Sending datagrids arraycollection to Java Servlet

Tags: java, apache-flex

I have an arraycollection in datagrid and i want to pass it to the servlet using .
Is there any way to do that? 
Here my problem is, i can send arraycollection through SEND() of HTTPSERVICE, but when to receive it in HTTPRequestObject of servlet, request.getParameter('paramName') will return String. So how can i receive the same arraycollection from flex to the servlet's request object?

Here

[Bindable]

public var dataAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

will be my variable to hold arraycollection.

When i am doing this,

mx:HTTPService
id="fileformatServlet" result="fileformatServlet_resultHandler(event)" fault="fileformatServlet_faultHandler(event)"
showBusyCursor="true"

and
fileformatServlet.send("arrayCollection":dataAC);

Now on java side,
request.getparameter("arrayCollection") will return a string not an arraycollection.Typecast is also not possible.

so what should i do now?

Comment: Can you share the code with us at least how you send the data and how to get it in server side(in your servlet code).

Answer (score 0):

Http request parameters are always pass as String. You have to serialize the Array in some format.

For example you can use Json forma t and deserialize it  in java.
[FlexJavaJson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122368/how-can-i-serialize-a-list-of-objects-using-flex-json)