# How to parse a class with List as a field using FlexJson JSONDeserializer?

Tags: java, json, deserialization, flexjson

I want to parse a string to a class which has a List as a field and also another object.
Here's the class:

```
Result result;
List<Param> params;
```

and the string:

```
{  
  "result":{  
    "isOk":true,
    "message":"OK"
  },
  "params":[  
    {  
      "id":123,
      "name":"ASD"
    },
    {  
      "id":987,
      "name":"QWE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099803/how-to-use-flexjson-jsondeserializer) I tried to use `.use()` option but I only managed to get a HashMap. The documentation is not clear for me.

Edit: Now I've made some changes to figure this out and can't even get the hashmap...

Edit2: Okay, I got the hashmap but it's crazy.

I've managed to do:

```
HashMap<String, List<Params>> map = 
  new JSONDeserializer<HashMap<String, List<Params>>>()
        .use("null", List.class)
        .use("params", Params.class)
        .deserialize(json);
```

then I do:

```
List<Params> params = mapa.get("params");
```

but `Param param = params.get(0);` returns failed cast HashMap to Params...